# how to draw the log-likelihood graph

Tags: r, mle

I am learning how to draw a log-likelihood graph. Please allow me briefly introduce what I want to do specifically:

Assume we have the data/vector as below:

```
set.seed(123)
sample <- rpois(50, 1.65)
```

And the `log_like` function is given as below:

```
log_like_graph <- function(lambda){
  X <- as.matrix(sample) # not sure whether this is necessary for one-parameter distribution.
  N <- nrow(X)
  logLik <- N*log(lambda) - lambda*N*mean(X)
  return(loglik)
}

log_like_graph <- Vectorize(log_like_graph)

# set range of lambda 
lambda_vals <- seq(-10,10,by=1)

log_vals <- outer(lambda_vals,log_like_graph)
```

Based on the above `lambda_vals` and `log_vals`, I expect to produce a plot like below:

[image: plot]

However, when I excute the last command: `log_vals <- outer(lambda_vals,log_like_graph)`, I got the error hint

> Error in as.vector(x, mode) :
> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Could you please help me solve this problem? Thank you very much!

(FYI: I mainly follow the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3drLH-DFpE&ab_channel=CalebLikesR that teaches to draw the curve for a log-likelihood function, although it uses normal distribution for demonstration.)

Comment: A closure is (essentially) a function, the error seems to be implying that you're treating a function which should be called to return a result as a result itself? My guess would be `sample`, perhaps test it's type and see if it can be coerced to a matrix as you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I see; no need to vectorise `log_like_graph` as you can just pass `lambda` values into it with `sapply` rather than `outer`, you are passing `lambda_vals < 0` but the support of lambda is >= 0, and I don't think your log-likelihood function is correct (I think it should be `-N * lambda - sum(lfactorial(sample)) + log(lambda) * sum(X)` but it is easier/more accurate to use `dpois(..., log=TRUE)`).

So fixing these things

```
# data
set.seed(123)
samples <- rpois(50, 1.65)

# The log-likelihood becomes
log_like_graph <- function(X, lambda){
  N <- NROW(X)
  logLik <- -N * lambda - sum(lfactorial(X)) + log(lambda) * sum(X)
  return(logLik)
}

# set lambda >= 0 and take smaller steps (0.01) for a smoother curve
lambda_vals <- seq(0,10,by=0.01)

# loop through lambda values calculating the log-likehood at each value
ll1 <- sapply(lambda_vals, function(i) log_like_graph(samples, i))
plot(lambda_vals, ll1, type="l")
```

This can also be done with `dpois(..., log=TRUE)` :

```
ll2 <- sapply(lambda_vals, function(i) sum(dpois(samples, lambda=i, log=TRUE)))
all.equal(ll1, ll2)
# [1] TRUE
```